# How can I make my screenlets run on startup?

Tags: startup, screenlets

I've installed screenlets and it seems to work fine. However, when I boot my computer I have to manually initiate every widget. I would like my widgets to initiate without me having to do anything, if possible. Screenlet deamon is already on startup applications.

Answer (score 2):

Someone on Google+ community just solved this for me. I quote:

> For every screentlet, there is an option to "launch on startup". Have
>   you started the screenlet-manager? If not you should, and leave it in
>   the status area﻿.

Best regards.